# Shorter divs within a grid to fill remaining vertical space + align list element to bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a grid which will be used to display products. Some titles and descriptions will be longer than others so I need to keep all the divs the same height for consistent styling. I've done this using `display: flex`.

That works quite well but I need to align the last child of each item to the bottom of it's parent. The last child is a button so it would look better if they were all lined up.

The issue I'm having is I have quite a few divs around the content and I don't want to add flexbox to all of that - I'm assuming that shouldn't be necessary but I'm no expert.

The highest level parents are all the same height. The next child wasn't but I think I've managed to resolve that by setting `height: 100%`. So the next problem is getting `mosaic__caption` to fill the space and with it the `.btn` to the bottom.

Here's my CodePen: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/JLBOyE

The first item is the one I've added more text to to make it taller and I've added opaque red backgrounds to the parents divs so we can see what is 100% and what isn't.

Any ideas?

```css
/**
 * Clearfix
 */
/**
 * Typography
 */
/**
 * Media Queries.
 * 
 * 1. $bp2  =  480px  (30rem)
 * 2. $bp3  =  600px  (37.5rem)
 * 3. $bp4  =  768px  (48rem)
 * 4. $bp5  =  1024px  (64rem)
 * 5. $bp6  =  1220px  (76.250rem)
 * 6. $bp7  =  1400px  (87.5rem)
 */
/**
 * Base
 */
/**
 * Colours
 */
/**
 * Spacing
 */
.mosaic {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 30px -15px;
  padding: 0;
  /* [1] */
  /* [2] */
  /* [3] */
  /* [4] */
  /* [5] */
  /* [6] */
}
.mosaic:before, .mosaic:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.mosaic:after {
  clear: both;
}
.mosaic:before, .mosaic:after {
  content: normal;
  /* [1] */
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .mosaic {
    margin-left: -30px;
  }
}

.mosaic__item {
  background: none;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: -15px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  /* [1] */
  /* [2] */
  /* [3] */
  /* [4] */
  /* [5] */
  /* [6] */
  /* [1] */
  /* [2] */
  /* [3] */
  /* [4] */
  /* [5] */
  /* [6] */
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .mosaic__item {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .mosaic__item:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 87.5em) {
  .mosaic__item {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }
  .mosaic__item:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: none;
  }
  .mosaic__item:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}

.mosaic__wrap {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.mosaic__link {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: none;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.mosaic__link:hover {
  background-color: #94121f;
}

.mosaic__image-wrap {
  background-image: none;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.mosaic__image {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.mosaic__item:hover .mosaic__image {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
          transform: scale(1.05);
}

.mosaic__caption {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #778586;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s;
  /* [1] */
  /* [2] */
  /* [3] */
  /* [4] */
  /* [5] */
  /* [6] */
}
.mosaic__link:hover .mosaic__caption {
  color: #fbdde0;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .mosaic__caption {
    padding: 30px 30px;
  }
}
.mosaic__caption .btn {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.mosaic__title {
  color: #0e1010;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 7.5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .20s;
  transition: all .20s;
  /* [1] */
  /* [2] */
  /* [3] */
  /* [4] */
  /* [5] */
  /* [6] */
}
.h-product .mosaic__title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.mosaic__title a {
  background-image: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-shadow: none;
}
@media (min-width: 37.5em) {
  .mosaic__title {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
.mosaic__link:hover .mosaic__title {
  color: white;
}

.mosaic__desc {
  margin-bottom: 7.5px;
}

.mosaic__value {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.mosaic__value .p-price {
  color: #0e1010;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.mosaic__review {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mosaic h-feed">
 <li class="mosaic__item h-product">
  <div class="mosaic__wrap">
   <a href="#" class="mosaic__image-wrap">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="mosaic__image u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
   </a>
   <div class="mosaic__caption">
    <a href="#" class="flag p-category">Special Offer</a>
    <h2 class="mosaic__title p-name"><a href="#" class="moasic__title-link">Name of Product that is really, really, really long</a></h2>
    <p class="mosaic__desc e-description">A long description to add more height to product</p>
    <div class="h-review mosaic__review">
     <data class="p-rating" value="3">
               3 Star rating here
     </data>
             </div>
    <p class="mosaic__value"><del>£4.95</del> <data class="p-price" value="4.05">£4.05</data></p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Add to Cart</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class="mosaic__item h-product">
  <div class="mosaic__wrap">
   <a href="#" class="mosaic__image-wrap">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="mosaic__image u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
   </a>
   <div class="mosaic__caption">
    <a href="#" class="flag p-category">Special Offer</a>
    <h2 class="mosaic__title p-name"><a href="#" class="moasic__title-link">Name of Product</a></h2>
    <p class="mosaic__desc e-description">A short description</p>
    <div class="h-review mosaic__review">
     <data class="p-rating" value="3">
               3 Star rating here
     </data>
             </div>
    <p class="mosaic__value"><del>£4.95</del> <data class="p-price" value="4.05">£4.05</data></p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Add to Cart</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class="mosaic__item h-product">
  <div class="mosaic__wrap">
   <a href="#" class="mosaic__image-wrap">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="mosaic__image u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
   </a>
   <div class="mosaic__caption">
    <a href="#" class="flag p-category">Special Offer</a>
    <h2 class="mosaic__title p-name"><a href="#" class="moasic__title-link">Name of Product</a></h2>
    <p class="mosaic__desc e-description">A short description</p>
    <div class="h-review mosaic__review">
     <data class="p-rating" value="3">
               3 Star rating here
     </data>
             </div>
    <p class="mosaic__value"><del>£4.95</del> <data class="p-price" value="4.05">£4.05</data></p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Add to Cart</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class="mosaic__item h-product">
  <div class="mosaic__wrap">
   <a href="#" class="mosaic__image-wrap">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="mosaic__image u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
   </a>
   <div class="mosaic__caption">
    <a href="#" class="flag p-category">Special Offer</a>
    <h2 class="mosaic__title p-name"><a href="#" class="moasic__title-link">Name of Product</a></h2>
    <p class="mosaic__desc e-description">A short description</p>
    <div class="h-review mosaic__review">
     <data class="p-rating" value="3">
               3 Star rating here
     </data>
             </div>
    <p class="mosaic__value"><del>£4.95</del> <data class="p-price" value="4.05">£4.05</data></p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Add to Cart</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class="mosaic__item h-product">
  <div class="mosaic__wrap">
   <a href="#" class="mosaic__image-wrap">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="mosaic__image u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
   </a>
   <div class="mosaic__caption">
    <a href="#" class="flag p-category">Special Offer</a>
    <h2 class="mosaic__title p-name"><a href="#" class="moasic__title-link">Name of Product</a></h2>
    <p class="mosaic__desc e-description">A short description</p>
    <div class="h-review mosaic__review">
     <data class="p-rating" value="3">
               3 Star rating here
     </data>
             </div>
    <p class="mosaic__value"><del>£4.95</del> <data class="p-price" value="4.05">£4.05</data></p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Add to Cart</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `.mosaic__wrap` and `.mosaic__caption` flexboxes. To maintain the vertical flow of content add `flex-direction: column` to both.

Then, to make `.mosaic__wrap` expand to fill the vertical height, add `flex: 1`.

```css
/**
 * Clearfix
 */


/**
 * Typography
 */


/**
 * Media Queries.
 * 
 * 1. $bp2  =  480px  (30rem)
 * 2. $bp3  =  600px  (37.5rem)
 * 3. $bp4  =  768px  (48rem)
 * 4. $bp5  =  1024px  (64rem)
 * 5. $bp6  =  1220px  (76.250rem)
 * 6. $bp7  =  1400px  (87.5rem)
 */


/**
 * Base
 */


/**
 * Colours
 */


/**
 * Spacing
 */

.mosaic {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 30px -15px;
  padding: 0;
  /* [1] */
  /* [2] */
  /* [3] */
  /* [4] */
  /* [5] */
  /* [6] */
}

.mosaic:before,
.mosaic:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.mosaic:after {
  clear: both;
}

.mosaic:before,
.mosaic:after {
  content: normal;
  /* [1] */
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .mosaic {
    margin-left: -30px;
  }
}

.mosaic__item {
  background: none;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: -15px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  /* [1] */
  /* [2] */
  /* [3] */
  /* [4] */
  /* [5] */
  /* [6] */
  /* [1] */
  /* [2] */
  /* [3] */
  /* [4] */
  /* [5] */
  /* [6] */
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .mosaic__item {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .mosaic__item:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 87.5em) {
  .mosaic__item {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }
  .mosaic__item:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: none;
  }
  .mosaic__item:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}

.mosaic__wrap {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.mosaic__link {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: none;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.mosaic__link:hover {
  background-color: #94121f;
}

.mosaic__image-wrap {
  background-image: none;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.mosaic__image {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.mosaic__item:hover .mosaic__image {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.mosaic__caption {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #778586;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s;
  /* [1] */
  /* [2] */
  /* [3] */
  /* [4] */
  /* [5] */
  /* [6] */
}

.mosaic__link:hover .mosaic__caption {
  color: #fbdde0;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .mosaic__caption {
    padding: 30px 30px;
  }
}

.mosaic__caption .btn {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.mosaic__title {
  color: #0e1010;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 7.5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .20s;
  transition: all .20s;
  /* [1] */
  /* [2] */
  /* [3] */
  /* [4] */
  /* [5] */
  /* [6] */
}

.h-product .mosaic__title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mosaic__title a {
  background-image: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-shadow: none;
}

@media (min-width: 37.5em) {
  .mosaic__title {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}

.mosaic__link:hover .mosaic__title {
  color: white;
}

.mosaic__desc {
  margin-bottom: 7.5px;
}

.mosaic__value {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.mosaic__value .p-price {
  color: #0e1010;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.mosaic__review {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* added styles */
.mosaic__wrap,
.mosaic__caption {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mosaic__caption {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mosaic h-feed">
  <li class="mosaic__item h-product">
    <div class="mosaic__wrap">
      <a href="#" class="mosaic__image-wrap">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="mosaic__image u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      </a>
      <div class="mosaic__caption">
        <a href="#" class="flag p-category">Special Offer</a>
        <h2 class="mosaic__title p-name"><a href="#" class="moasic__title-link">Name of Product that is really, really, really long</a></h2>
        <p class="mosaic__desc e-description">A long description to add more height to product</p>
        <div class="h-review mosaic__review">
          <data class="p-rating" value="3">
               3 Star rating here
     </data>
        </div>
        <p class="mosaic__value"><del>£4.95</del> <data class="p-price" value="4.05">£4.05</data></p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Add to Cart</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="mosaic__item h-product">
    <div class="mosaic__wrap">
      <a href="#" class="mosaic__image-wrap">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="mosaic__image u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      </a>
      <div class="mosaic__caption">
        <a href="#" class="flag p-category">Special Offer</a>
        <h2 class="mosaic__title p-name"><a href="#" class="moasic__title-link">Name of Product</a></h2>
        <p class="mosaic__desc e-description">A short description</p>
        <div class="h-review mosaic__review">
          <data class="p-rating" value="3">
               3 Star rating here
     </data>
        </div>
        <p class="mosaic__value"><del>£4.95</del> <data class="p-price" value="4.05">£4.05</data></p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Add to Cart</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="mosaic__item h-product">
    <div class="mosaic__wrap">
      <a href="#" class="mosaic__image-wrap">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="mosaic__image u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      </a>
      <div class="mosaic__caption">
        <a href="#" class="flag p-category">Special Offer</a>
        <h2 class="mosaic__title p-name"><a href="#" class="moasic__title-link">Name of Product</a></h2>
        <p class="mosaic__desc e-description">A short description</p>
        <div class="h-review mosaic__review">
          <data class="p-rating" value="3">
               3 Star rating here
     </data>
        </div>
        <p class="mosaic__value"><del>£4.95</del> <data class="p-price" value="4.05">£4.05</data></p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Add to Cart</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="mosaic__item h-product">
    <div class="mosaic__wrap">
      <a href="#" class="mosaic__image-wrap">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="mosaic__image u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      </a>
      <div class="mosaic__caption">
        <a href="#" class="flag p-category">Special Offer</a>
        <h2 class="mosaic__title p-name"><a href="#" class="moasic__title-link">Name of Product</a></h2>
        <p class="mosaic__desc e-description">A short description</p>
        <div class="h-review mosaic__review">
          <data class="p-rating" value="3">
               3 Star rating here
     </data>
        </div>
        <p class="mosaic__value"><del>£4.95</del> <data class="p-price" value="4.05">£4.05</data></p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Add to Cart</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="mosaic__item h-product">
    <div class="mosaic__wrap">
      <a href="#" class="mosaic__image-wrap">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="mosaic__image u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      </a>
      <div class="mosaic__caption">
        <a href="#" class="flag p-category">Special Offer</a>
        <h2 class="mosaic__title p-name"><a href="#" class="moasic__title-link">Name of Product</a></h2>
        <p class="mosaic__desc e-description">A short description</p>
        <div class="h-review mosaic__review">
          <data class="p-rating" value="3">
               3 Star rating here
     </data>
        </div>
        <p class="mosaic__value"><del>£4.95</del> <data class="p-price" value="4.05">£4.05</data></p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Add to Cart</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That looks great, I'll test it later! I'm always a bit sceptical about using `flex` lots of child elements but I guess it's not a problem and it is needed. I think that does back to when browser support wasn't great, I should really think of it no different than `inline` or `block` or stuff like this now.

Comment: Yeah, use it as much as you need. :)